# How to create a list comprehension based on generating lists of a given size with elements in a given range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Given two parameters:

- `dim` the length of a sub-list
- `n` the range of values each element of this list may take

I want to produce a list of lists such that the result contains all the unique combinations of sub-lists (for `dim` and `n`)

For example:

```
dim = 3
n = 2
```

I want to generate:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1]
]
```

For:

```
dim = 2
n = 3
```

I want to generate:

```
[
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 0],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2]
]
```

I have tried:

```
[[a,b] for a in range(dim) for b in range(n)]
```

but that is not quite right. I have been scratching my head around this for a while now. I just cannot see how to do that.

Note, I was assuming list comprehensions was the way to go. Other methods are also welcome. But I thought list comprehensions was a good way, since I'm going to add more restrictions later. Like

```
[[a,b] for a in range(dim) for b in range(n) if a!=b]
```

That last condition `a!=b` is a very simple condition. In reality, they will be more on the form "If `a` belongs to this set, and `b` to another set and ab+4`.

The goal with this code is to create a function that can take a fretted instrument like guitar, receive number of strings, their tuning and a chord, and then it should spit out the possible ways of fingering. However, I am concerned about performance because I want to handle at least six strings with twelve different notes. But that's a problem I'll worry about later.

So a sample of the complete could be something like this. `tuning` is simply a list where the size is number of strings and the elements are the tuning. And `chord` is some kind of structure that defines valid outputs.

```
>>> get_fingerings(tuning, chord)
[[6,6,4,3,0,0], [1,3,0,0,3]]
```

Comment: Do you have to do it with a list comprehension? I'll bet there's a function in `itertools` that will do it for you.

Comment: Work through a tutorial on `itertools`; you['re asking for the `product` method.

Comment: @Barmar I clarified it

Comment: so you want a function `foo(dim, n)` such that `foo(3,2)` produces `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]` right? Each sub-list in the result is length "dim" and each value is in the range `n` right?

Comment: @JonSG Exactly.

Comment: I have an answer but the question is closed. I'm going to edit it a bit to see if we can get it open again as I personally think the question is a good one and the answer was not obvious (at least to me).  In the event that we can not reopen the question try `def foo(dim, n): return itertools.product(*[range(n) for _ in range(dim)])` I think you get the results you seek by `for i in foo(3,2): print(i)`

Comment: @JonSG That's appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension with `itertools.product` as a generator of tuples and whatever filter to include or exclude them from the final list. For example:

```
[item for item 
    in itertools.product(range(5), range(5)) # generate
    if item[0] != item[1]]                   # filter in/out
```

Comment: My apologies @DYZ as I see you are actually very close to an answer for `foo(2, 5)`.  I hope my prior question did not lead to someone downvoting this. I'm upvoting this :-)

Comment: This did the trick. However, I used `product(range(n), repeat=dim)`

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is just `a != b != ...`, then just simply use `itertools.permutations`:

`[i for i in  permutations(range(n), dim)]`

Like:
`[i for i in  permutations(range(2), 2)]` => `[(0, 1), (1, 0)]`

Comment: This is not really what I want. This is missing (0,0) and (1,1)

Comment: This is only for the simple condition in your question.
If you have other conditions, just use `product` method.